# Stop CSS transition from firing on page load

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm experiencing an issue with the CSS `transition` property beeing fired on page load.

The problem is that when I apply a `color` `transition` to an element, (ex: `transition: color .2s`) then when the page first loads my elements flashes from black to it's own assigned color.

Supposing I have the following code:

### CSS

```
p.green {
   color: green;
   transition: color .2s;
   -moz-transition: color .2s;
   -webkit-transition: color .2s;
   -o-transition: color .2s;
}

p.green:hover {
   color: yellow;
}
```

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN'
'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <p class="green">The Flashing Text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

On page load, my `p.green` will fade from `black` to `green`.

I don't want to apply the color transition to the `:hover` pseudo class as that would not apply the transition *onMouseLeave*.

I'ts really annoying having the text flashing across the webpage. Up to this moment I have been avoiding using transitions unless I really need them and even so I use with care. It would be great if there is some really obvious solution to this that I'm not seeing!

This happens on Google Chrome. I haven't tested in other browsers.

[jsfiddle.net/ShyZp/2](http://jsfiddle.net/ShyZp/2/)  *(thanks @Shmiddty)*

Comment: Quick thought: `window.onload = function(){document.body.className += " loaded";}` `body.loaded p.green{transition:color .2s;}`

Comment: That would work if you have only a small number of classes with color transition. I'm looking for a non JavaScript answer preferably...

Comment: I can't recreate the problem in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/ShyZp/

Comment: the problem doesn't happen for me in chrome, provide us with your exact code in a jsfiddle please...

Comment: @Shmiddty I had tryed a jsfiddle before too and could not recreate it. Not sure if it's because of the page scripts... I only see the text appearing almost at the end of the page load so maybe that ruins the effect... Ill try doing some more tests...

Comment: are the `body{color:red;}` and `p.green{color:green;}` in separate files?

Comment: The problem can be seen here, but this is only valid if the two declarations aren't happening in the same file: http://jsfiddle.net/ShyZp/2/

Comment: Or, to be more specific, if `p.green` isn't defined before the elements are created.

Comment: @Shmiddty yes, I have a separate css file which I call on my html file header. Thta's exacly the problem I'm having. Thanks for the working fiddle!

Comment: Can you update your question to include the basic/reduced HTML structure include which files each style is declared in, and how each stylesheet is included?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

@Shmiddty comments on this question left me thinking, so I have been playing around with the  code and found a solution.

The problem lies on the `header` declarations. By inverting the order of the CSS and JS external file calls - i.e. putting the CSS before the JS - the color transitions stop firing on page load:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

My guess is that the JS load was delaying the load of the CSS to after the DOM was ready. By that time (as @Shmiddty suggested) the text had already been assigned the default browser color and was then using my CSS `transition` declaration to fade into its styled color.

** I'm still not sure this is the most appropriate way to do it, but it works. If anyone has a better solution please feel free to add or edit.

Comment: This is a hit or miss solution - it may work today but fail tomorrow when you make code changes.

Comment: I can also reproduce the issue without a single JS file, so this answer won't solve my issue.  The accepted one dones tho.

Comment: This answer sounds like your issue was caching.

Comment: It seems that this workaround with positioning the <script> still doesn't work if JavaScript is disabled in the browser.

Answer (score 140):

There is a **[bug](https://lab.laukstein.com/bug/input)** in Chrome that causes CSS transitions to fire if the page includes a `<form>` element.

One simple fix is to add a script tag containing a single space to the footer of the page.

```
<script> </script>
```

You can follow the bug at https://crbug.com/332189 and https://crbug.com/167083.

Comment: I had `<script async src="main.js"></script>` at the end of my document. Removing the `async` attribute fixed the unwanted transitions on page load. 

Comment: Like @KyleFox I had a `defer` on my `<script>` tag and removing it solved my issue. I just moved the script to the bottom of the doc after that.

Comment: This worked inconsistently for me (previously the bug happened 100% of the time; with this change it happened 50% of the time). What *did* work 100% of the time, which this answer inspired me to try, was reordering stuff in the `<head>` of my document so that my CSS was included *before* my JavaScript instead of after it; I literally solved the bug by moving my Google Analytics `<script>` tag around. There's clearly some race condition or timing issue in Chrome that can be smoothed out by the delay caused by interpreting a bit of JS, although the precise mechanics are mysterious to me.

Comment: FWIW, I was still having this issue even with no JS on the page. The only thing that fixed it for me was moving the CSS to the start of the `<body>` tag. I added `<link rel="preload" href="main.css" as="style">` to the `<head>` so it would still download right away.

Comment: I didn't have a <form> element in my page and it solved the bug

Comment: I am not sure how this works but I added this right before my `</head>` tag and it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 18):

Add to your CSS:

```
.css-transitions-only-after-page-load * {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
   transition: none !important;
}
```

And add some code to your global JavaScript file:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  setTimeout(() => $(".css-transitions-only-after-page-load").removeClass("css-transitions-only-after-page-load"), 10);
});
```

Now you can mark any element on your page with *css-transitions-only-after-page-load* class:

```
<div class="container css-transitions-only-after-page-load">
...
</div>
```

Comment: I don't like to have to use JS to fix this issue but it works well. The empty `<script>` answer did not do the trick for me.

Comment: in 2023 same issue.. try to put this in head instead of footer it worked for me

Answer (score 7):

nienn [posts the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14416030/1709587). The problem lies in the document head, and where/how you are loading your stylesheets. It's similar to the "can't modify headers, they're already sent" in PHP, except HTML/CSS/webkit doesn't throw you an error.

I was experiencing this exact problem, read nienn's post, and I reviewed my head. Here were my contents previously.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <html lang="en">
    <meta name="description" content="A website for me to do whatever I want with." >
    <title>My title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mD/media/foot.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mD/media/head.css" type="text/css">
</head>
```

Notice I'm not loading any JS, also note of how I was loading the style sheets page after specifying the title. After moving the stylesheet-references to the 'back', it worked like a charm. The end result looked like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <html lang="en">
    <meta name="description" content="A website for me to do whatever I want with." >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mD/media/foot.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mD/media/head.css" type="text/css">
    <title>My title</title>
</head>
```

It's not only javascript that can cause this problem, but the site title as well. I guess a good rule of thumb is css > js > site title.

Comment: Just to add I had the same issue and it turned out it was a video delaying the page load. Removing the video on iOS fixed the issue.

Comment: Can you add MDN or w3.org reference to back up your claim? This solution doesn't work in the latest browsers.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer did not do the trick for me. There's a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332189) in Google Chrome that can be avoided just by **adding a script in the page**. Even an empty script solves the problem.

Comment: Surprised that this bug has been going on for years. Just to add to the answer, the `<script>` tags must go after the DOM elements you're experiencing the problem with. I'd recommend just putting it at the end of your page.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to solve this problem is to use the single space, empty `<script>` fix found in the answers on this page.  However I've found 2 other ways to solve this problem.

1. Place the CSS of the offending element(s) inside a `<style>` tag in the header of your HTML file.  The bug only occurs when the CSS is called from an external stylesheet.
2. Place the offending element(s) in a `flexbox` container.  This fixes the bug as well.

Comment: this is the solution if you have no js file and don't want to use js

Answer (score 4):

You can just add an empty script tag to your html file.

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but it should include at least one character. Either space or new line (\n) or comment (//) or whatever

```
<script type="text/javascript"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">//</script>
```

Or just link a js file to your html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

You can place the script tag everywhere you want. In the **head** or **body** tag.

This problem only happen during development because at the final situation of a website it will definitely have a js file

Comment: That empty space is necessary! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To fix CSS transition from firing on page load for me, the cause was Google Adsense script header, i.e.

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=..." crossorigin></script>
```

The fix is to remove the `async` attribute

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=..." crossorigin></script>
```

If you are wondering why it works, I don't know for sure.

I just think it's kinda funny how Google's script broke it's browser. It wasn't so funny trying to solve this for hours.

Comment: This is crazy in 2023 is still an issue, I could never figure out of this if I didn't found this question! Anyway for me to work I had to add in the head <script> </script> not footer.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried using different transition properties? Such as:

```
-moz-transition: color .2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: color .2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: color .2s; /* Opera */
```

Worked just fine for me in Chrome.

EDIT: You answered the question about browsers already. You should try using -webkit-transform

Comment: I'm using that, sorry, just thought I'd put a simplified code on the question.

Comment: Alright, by the way, I thought IE doesn't support CSS3 transitions?

Comment: Well there you go! :) You are right of course! Have been stuck on Chrome for this one, went to IE just for this question sake and didn't even thought about that *minor detail...