# CSS Transition flash on page load with NextJS production build

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, css-transitions, next.js, visual-glitch

On my production build (`npm run build && npm run start`) of my NextJS app I noticed elements firing a css transition on page load (links flashing blue, svg flashing color).

Noticed in Chrome only, Firefox and Safari didn't have this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer [in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42969608/943337). Appearantly it is due to a chrome bug (https://crbug.com/332189 and https://crbug.com/167083).

Fix is to put a script tag with one space at the end of the body. In NextJS you can do this by adding a `pages/_document.js` file ([more info](https://nextjs.org/docs#custom-document)).

Mine looks like this now:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
    render () {
        return (
            <Html lang="en">
                <Head>
                    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"/>
                </Head>
                <body>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                    {/* Empty script tag as chrome bug fix, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42969608/943337 */}
                    <script> </script>
                </body>
            </Html>
        )
    }
}
```

Edit: This bug might be [fixed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332189#c68) since June 1st 2021 in Chrome Canary v93.0.4529.0 after 7.5 years!

Comment: This is genius! Thank you so much!

Comment: Also try closing the Chrome dev tool, and see if this is your issue. For me it was.

Comment: This is amazing