# Chrome transitions from default property value to specified value on page load when using external stylesheet

Tags: css, css-transitions

I've built a simple dialog/popup using CSS.

Its initial state (when closed) has `opacity: 0`.

When the dialog is open (using `:target`) I set `opacity: 1`.

I'm using `transition: opacity 2s` to make the transition smooth.

I've used this dialog CSS for years, but noticed today that on page load Chrome transitions the dialog from `opacity: 1` to its initial state of `opacity: 0`.

This did not happen before.

It does not happen if I put the CSS in the HTML inside a `style` element.

Why is this happening? When did it start happening (in what version of Chrome?) It's clearly a bug (in Chrome/Webkit) as far as I can tell? How can I stop it from happening? (I'm on 86.0.4240.75 btw)

[Example with external stylesheet where you can see the bug](http://sleek.wpengine.com/transition-test/)

[Example with style element where the bug does not occur](http://sleek.wpengine.com/transition-test/?style)

(Note that you may need to do a hard refresh to experience the bug)

The CSS in question;

```css
div.dialog {
    /* Size - not too wide, not too tall */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 40rem;
    max-height: 90%;

    /* Position on top of everything */
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 101;

    /* In the center of the viewport */
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    /* For looking "good" */
    background: white;
    padding: 3rem;
    border: 1px solid black;

    /* When closed */
    /* NOTE: This is where things go wrong, even though opacity: 0; is set here initially, for some reason Chrome renders the element with opacity: 1 and then transitions to 0, this does _not_ happen if this CSS is inside a style element */
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s ease;
}

/* When open */
div.dialog:target {
    pointer-events: all;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Edit: I added `a {color: red; transition: color 2s}` to the stylesheet now too. Same thing happens with the link, it transitions from blue/purple (if you've visited it) to my specified red on page load.

Edit: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1136630

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop CSS transition from firing on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389566/stop-css-transition-from-firing-on-page-load)

Answer (score 0):

It is duplicated with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389566/stop-css-transition-from-firing-on-page-load#)

you can solve this problem with just adding an empty script tag to html. But you should append a character at least.

```
<script> </script>
```

Comment: if the question is duplicate flag as duplicate of add a comment